# What is RA abbreviation for?

Tags: word-meaning, abbreviations

In a [joke image](https://www.pinterest.se/pin/7951736821034225/?utm_campaign=category_pp&e_t=6b4e2c86fe94439f9af4be6977e0a121&utm_content=7951736821034225&utm_source=31&utm_term=3&utm_medium=2012&news_id=4956094998243192337) (second image from top), there's mentioning of *preparing for RA inspection*.

Googling leads to medical material on rheumatism and [disambiguitization](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RA) produces way too many different results.

What could RA mean in the context of inspecting a room, flat or, possibly, bathroom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that stands for Resident Assistant.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_assistant):

> "A resident assistant (also variously known as a house fellow, resident advisor, community assistant, resident mentor, residence don, peer advisor, community advisor, collegiate fellow, or senior resident), commonly shortened to **RA**, is a trained peer leader who supervises those living in a residence hall or group housing facility. The majority of RAs work at colleges, universities, or residential mental health and substance abuse facilities."

Comment: Yup. I think this refers to a college dorm RA.